# New index to heap, does the order of columns in sql index matter?

Tags: sql, indexing

We have a table without indexes (heap) with 3 columns (A, B, C, D, E). 
We need to create new indexes to this selects:

```
SELECT A FROM T1 WHERE A=1 AND C=3
SELECT D FROM T1 WHERE C=4 and A=1
```

If I create 2 indexes like this make sense? Or is it the same?

```
CREATE INDEX  indexC1 ON T1(A, C);
CREATE INDEX  indexC2 ON T1(C, A);
```

Comment: I think its the same thing because the hash of both the values is stored as an index. So if you ever want to put a filter/join criteria on both the columns it will work irrespective of the order.

Comment: You're thinking about it slightly the wrong way around. The order of columns in an index does matter, but the order of appearance of columns in a `WHERE` clause *doesn't*.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both are same. Index stored both column.
2. Now if Table does not have key then you can create cluster index which is solve all you problem.( Performance)
3. In case if you create non cluster then to improve the performance use **covering index** (in case if you are using SQL Server Similar exists in other DB as well but I am not 100% sure).

   - By using covering index you can put column that you use in Select Like A or D or Any other column that are not part of index but it is part of result.

Answer (score 0):

it's different

#### SQLServer example:

```
CREATE INDEX  indexC2 ON T1(C, A);
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE C=4  --it will run index,because C is first key

CREATE INDEX  indexC2 ON T1(C, A);
SELECT D FROM T1 WHERE A=4  --it won't run index,because when it run 
                            --will check is C first key or not
                            --if C is first key then check A key
```